# Prevent Chrome Extension CSS from being Over Written by Websites

Tags: css, iframe, google-chrome-extension

I am working on an interesting chrome Extension. On certain websites, the CSS of the extension distorts because the website's css over rides my extension's css.

I realize that these scenarios have been posted to stackoverflow before but almost all the answers suggest that I use an IFrame.

I am not very content over the notion to use an IFrame because sometimes I have to change websites content and for this I will have to find way arounds while using IFrame.

I have come up with the following solutions

1. Introducing my custom CSS class naming conventions and applying those classes to my chrome extension elements.

For Example:

```
.Extension-Name-classname{
// css code
}

<element class=".Extension-Name-classname"> </element>
```

2. Use Web Components. My notion is that since every web component has its own CSS - it will solve my case.

What should be the bet way to solve this issue?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what your trying to do, but if you're injecting some html element and want your css to always [take precedence on that element](http://www.vanseodesign.com/css/css-specificity-inheritance-cascaade/) and its children, you should give that element an ID and always use it -

```
<element id="my-extension-spacename">
   <element class="class-name-1">
   </element>
   <element class="class-name-2">
   </element>
</element>

#my-extension-spacename .class-name-1 {
   // css code
}

#my-extension-spacename .class-name-2 {
   // css code
}
```

Comment: This isn't ideal because you don't know what properties external css will override and you probably don't want to set 100 properties per unique element in your html.